# Visual basic database issues

Tags: database

I have a database (access 2010) linked with my visual basic project. I am doing a login form and I got code but I get errors.

Here is the code:

```
Public Class start

Dim loginerror As String

Public Function login()

    Dim DBconn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim user As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim username As String
    Dim userDB As String
    Dim passDB As String
    Dim UserFound As Boolean

    DBconn.Open("Prodider = Microsoft.ace.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                 "data source = '" & Application.StartupPath & "\sellgames.accdb'")

    user.Open("usertable", DBconn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)

    UserFound = False
    login = False
    username = "Username = '" & txtbxuser.Text & "'"

    Do
        user.Find(username)
        If user.BOF = False And user.EOF = False Then
            userDB = user.Fields("username").Value.ToString

            passDB = user.Fields("Password").Value.ToString

            If userDB <> txtbxuser.Text Then
                user.MoveNext()

            Else
                UserFound = True
                If passDB = txtbxpass.Text Then
                    user.Close()
                    DBconn.Close()
                    Return True
                Else
                    loginerror = "Invalid Password"
                    user.Close()
                    DBconn.Close()
                    Return False

                End If
            End If
        Else
            loginerror = "Invalid username"
            user.Close()
            DBconn.Close()
            Return False

        End If
    Loop Until UserFound = True

    'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDdTOyIy_dU

End Function

Private Sub btnexit_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnexit.Click
    Me.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub btnregister_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnregister.Click
    register.ShowDialog()

End Sub

Private Sub btnlogin_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click
    If login() = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("logged in!", "login message")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(loginerror, "login message")
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

And here is the error:

*A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in sellgames.exe*

errors are on lines 14 and 15.

I have added the microsoft active x data objects 2.5 library

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Which line throws the exception?  Is there any more information about the exception, such as a message or stack trace of inner exception(s)?

Comment: Did you Google your error? [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814912) is documentation with a work-around. Did you try the work-around?

Answer (score 0):

DBconn.Open("provider and not prodider. check your spelling pls

Comment: Might want to check yours too. It's spelled "please", not "pls".